# Как на PHP из многомерного массива получить двумерный?

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из многоуровневого массива такого типа:

```
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "futbolki"
  "title" => "футболки"
  "parrent" => array:3 [▼
    "name" => "futbolki-i-polo"
    "title" => "футболки и поло"
    "parrent" => array:3 [▼
      "name" => "odezhda"
      "title" => "одежда"
      "parrent" => array:2 [▼
        "name" => "odezhda-obuv-i-aksessuary"
        "title" => "одежда, обувь и аксессуары"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

получить нечто похожее на такой формат:

```
$array[0] = [
  "name" => "futbolki"
  "title" => "футболки"
]
$array[1] = [
  "name" => "futbolki-i-polo"
  "title" => "футболки и поло"
]
$array[2] = [
  "name" => "odezhda"
  "title" => "одежда"
]
$array[3] = [
  "name" => "odezhda-obuv-i-aksessuary"
  "title" => "одежда, обувь и аксессуары"
]
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: попробуйте хоть что-то сделать самостоятельно, а не перекладывать свои задачи на других. Когда-то надо чему-то учиться, хотя бы погуглить

Comment: Каких-то стандартных функций для этого нет. Все надо реализовывать самостоятельно.  В вашем случае можно решить через рекурсию.

Comment: @newman в целом тут достаточно цикла `while(isset($item['parent']){...}`

Comment: @teran это, если предполагать, что всегда одна ветка, без ветвлений. Что возможно, и верно, поскольку это восходящая ветвь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочее решение, но в следующий раз сделайте сами, ведь это так просто (:

```php
<?php
function convert(array $array) {
    $result = [];
    $result[] = [
        "name" => $array["name"],
        "title" => $array["title"]
    ];
    if (isset($array["parrent"]))
        $result = array_merge($result, convert($array["parrent"]));
    return $result;
}
var_dump(convert([
  "name" => "futbolki",
  "title" => "футболки",
  "parrent" => [
    "name" => "futbolki-i-polo",
    "title" => "футболки и поло",
    "parrent" => [
      "name" => "odezhda",
      "title" => "одежда",
      "parrent" => [
        "name" => "odezhda-obuv-i-aksessuary",
        "title" => "одежда, обувь и аксессуары"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]));
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "futbolki"
    ["title"]=>
    string(16) "футболки"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "futbolki-i-polo"
    ["title"]=>
    string(28) "футболки и поло"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "odezhda"
    ["title"]=>
    string(12) "одежда"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(25) "odezhda-obuv-i-aksessuary"
    ["title"]=>
    string(48) "одежда, обувь и аксессуары"
  }
}
```

P.s.Хочу заметить, что в этом коде НЕ проверяются типы значений и НЕ добавляются в результат значения кроме "name" и "title"!

Comment: Спасибо тебе! Ты потрясающий человек и очень мне помог =)))

Comment: @ИльяПокровский, всегда рад помочь)

Answer (score 1):

При такой структуре данных можно обойтись без рекурсии, что всегда хорошо:

```
function convert(array $array)
{
    $result = [];   
    while($array) {
        $result[] = [
            "name" => $array["name"],
            "title" => $array["title"]
        ];
        $array = $array["parrent"] ?? [];
    }
    return $result;
}
```